# Is there a public OGC Catalog Service (CSW) available?

Tags: ogc, csw, catalog-service

Is there an "almost always available" service URL for a public Catalog Service (CSW) available anywhere?

I'm keen to test CSW client capabilities without having to configure a CSW server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bluenet:

http://imosmest.aodn.org.au/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home

and its GetCapabilities:

https://catalogue-imos.aodn.org.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&request=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 2):

You can also see a list of CSW (using [pycsw](http://pycsw.org/)) server deployments at https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/wiki/Live-Deployments

Comment: Thanks Tom - so far I have not been able to find a Profile to use with the CSW Client for ArcGIS that results in a successful search but I will keep trying.