# Servers that implement OGC Geo/Time OpenSearch

Tags: ogc, services

The OGC is has published the ["OpenSearch Geo and Time Extensions"](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/opensearchgeo). That specification is based on, but extends, the [OpenSearch Geo](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Geo/1.0/Draft_2) extension and [OpenSearch Time](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/Extensions/Time/1.0/Draft_1) extension.

As it turns out, I'm working on an open source (C#) implementation of the client side for OpenSearch. I'd like to include support for the OGC extensions to query by Geo and Time.

There are publicly available servers that implement the Geo and Time extensions, especially in the earth observation area (e.g. [NASA Echo](https://api.echo.nasa.gov/opensearch/)). However they don't implement the "extra" bits defined by OGC.

Are there any publicly available servers that implement any of the OGC extensions to the original OpenSearch Geo/Time extensions? In particular, I'm looking for implementations that expose the spatial and temporal containment operations ("relation" parameter).

Publicly available is preferred because:

- Saves work in setting up a test server
- Unit tests can be written that use it directly
- Avoids confirmation bias in testing

However in the absence of publicly available, anything implementing the draft OGC spec (even "git branch" level maturity) would be better than what I have now.

Comment: Is this question relevant any longer assuming that the specification has been out for some time now?

Comment: I think it is still relevant - it isn't really about the state of the extension, but rather about test servers. The first paragraph was outdated and I've reworked it, but the test of it stands.

Comment: In the [specification document](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=56866) there is a list of contacts, perhaps they would know of implementations.  I had a feeling that implementations must exist prior to an OGC standard being published...

Comment: No answers in nearly 4 years suggests that this question needs to be reviewed.  It seems to be seeking a list of "Servers that implement OGC Geo/Time OpenSearch" which makes it too broad.

Comment: @PolyGeo: I wasn't looking for a list - I was looking for one. The on-hold tells me to provide enough detail to identify an adequate answer. As written, I'd see that the answer could be a specific server instance or open source implementation; or a statement that there are no available instances (with some kind of evidence - not just an assertion).  Do you have a particular kind of edit in mind? Or are you just trying to avoid old, unanswered questions?

Comment: I have asked one, two or maybe more questions like this in the past (e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32027) but having seen similar questions seek one item at the outset and then stay open to receive multiple items (aka a list) I have come to realize that while the asker might be satisfied with just one the question is open-ended and likely to attract a list.

Comment: This question caught my attention because it was old, unanswered and upvoted.  Closing as I have done is one way to move it from the unanswered list but the other way is to provide an answer that says "As far as I know there are none".  To this question I could not say that with authority but as the asker you could certainly provide that as a self-answer.  If you wish to do that ping me and I'll be happy to insta-open it.

Comment: I'll do another scan, and try to provide a self-answer one way or the other.

Comment: pycsw supports the OGC OpenSearch Geo and Time Extensions 1.0 ~ https://docs.pycsw.org/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/